# running a ruby script online

Tags: ruby, slack

I've created a simple ruby script to automate my slack tags for employee's via a bot.

I was wondering if there are any services that are available to run this code constantly 24/7, this code loops on it's self and run's every 24 hours.

Comment: Heroku? Amazon AWS? Google Cloud Platform?

Answer (score 0):

If your script runs on a web server and can be triggered from the Internet by a http request you can use a web CRON service.

One service that works very well and is also free is [cron-job.org](https://cron-job.org/en/).